# Elixir : Feed content from a file to a function in command line

Tags: bash, shell, elixir

I have a csv type file. I want to be able to call a function from the command line, and feed it the content of this file - not the file itself.

I tried to call

```
mix run lib/my_module.ex $(cat tmp.txt)
```

having in the end of my module file :

```
IO.puts MyModule.my_func(System.argv)
```

Content is correctly processed to the func, but `System.argv` being a list of strings, it lost its format and is not possible to parse correctly.

If I instead try to

```
mix run -e "MyModule.my_func(:args)"
```

I can't find how to feed it the content of the file, using `cat` or something else.

How to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put between quotes, like this: `mix run lib/my_module.ex "$(cat tmp.txt)"`

Comment: I have been given another advice also, that looks very promising : to look at `stdin` when calling the function like that `cat tmp.csv | mix run lib/my_module.ex`

Comment: `stdin` might become your enemy all of a sudden on non-ascii content (e.g. backspace of like.)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me. Pass the *name* of the file only and do [`File.read/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/File.html#read/1) *inside* your module.

Somewhat like:

```
mix run lib/my_module.ex tmp.txt
```

and in your module:

```
System.argv
|> File.read!()
|> MyModule.my_func() 
|> IO.puts()
```

Comment: Sure, I would... But for some reason I don't have the file - it's some server work that gives me its content. Otherwise I already had the code working.

Comment: Then store it in the shell variable, pass the name of the variable to Elixir and read its content from inside your module :)